# Easy way to rename a project in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have downloaded an Android project. To avoid name conflicts I want to move it from
com.android.zzz to com.my.zzz.
At the moment I'm using Ecplise with the standard android toolkit. Is there a better way to do the rename than to go manually through the files?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is basic IDE refactoring.

Right click the package in Eclipse -> Refactor -> Rename.

You will probably want to check all the options that come up in the Rename dialog.

Another option would be to right click the class files in Eclipse -> Refactor -> Move.

Comment: This doesn't change the manifest but only the .java files. As a result it leaves errors.

Comment: If you actually check all those boxes in the dialog that comes up, it should change all your files except the Manifest file since the package and class names in the Manifest are separate.  That gives you 1 file to fix after the refactor.  Much better than going "manually through the files" as you put it in your original question.

Comment: There are no checkboxes in the dialog that comes up when selecting Refactor > Rename. The only thing in that dialog is an edit box labeled 'New name'.

Comment: This proceeded to move all my project's folders to the newly named project until it hit a "symlinked" (or eclipse's equivalent) folder, whereupon it failed and left my project divided at that point between the two names. Luckily it was a basic hello world type.

Comment: I just used this and it changed the package names in my manifest file... maybe this is a new feature.

Answer (score 9):

As usual, by pressing F2 on package name, you can rename or change the package name, and also by Right-clicking and then select Rename option, you can change or rename the Package name.

When you press F2, it will show you the dialog box as:

alt text

In this dialog, dont forget to check "Update references" check box because by making "check" to this check-box, it will make changes to all the references of the package which are referred by other components of project.

Hope this helps you,