# Android project Refactor greyed out

Tags: android, eclipse, refactoring, eclipse-plugin

I renamed a project in Eclipse via 'Refactor > Rename' as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845913/easy-way-to-rename-a-project-in-android/3846417#3846417).

I now want to rename it again, but the Refactor menu has *only one* menu item now (Android > Extract Android String...) which is also greyed out!

I am using Eclipse 3.6.1 with the latest Android SDK 9.

Why is that and how to I restore this to normal?

**Update (1):** After following Sankar Ganesh's suggestion (selecting a string), the Refactor menu appeared again. I then selected the Rename... menu item again and I received the following error message box:

[image]

This is much better than the previous situation, in which I had no idea why the Refactor menu had been disabled and what to do. Still, I don't understand why this is and what rules I should follow when using the Refactor function. I only wanted to rename a project... that's all. :)

**Update (2):** I just tried the same exact operation again again (Refactor > Rename while the project is selected in Project Explorer) and it worked! (without issuing the message box shown above).

What's going on?

Must be a bug, because this is clearly *inconsistent*.

Comment: Could you please select the project in the Package Explorer View and try again?

Comment: @Madhusuthanan Seethara Yes, I just did so -- and the problem persists. I also tried closing the project and Refactor -- didn't help. I re-opened the project and Refactor -- didn't help. I exited Eclipse completely, then re-started it -- didn't help. BTW, Refactor is greyed out for ALL projects in Project Explorer, not only the renamed one. This almost looks like a bug, unless this is a feature I am not aware of. Thanks.

Comment: @AndroidEve Sorry for rushing my answer. I experimented this on my eclipse and when the project was not selected the rename was disabled. It came back again when I selected the project. To be doubly sure I did this after renaming once (to reproduce your case). Probably a bug? BTW, what version of eclipse are you in? Can you try refreshing the project once? (not sure if it will solve the issue, but just a wild idea!)

Comment: Could it be because your Eclipse Java setting is pointing to a JRE instead of JDK ?

Comment: @Abhinav No. This isn't possible.

Comment: @Madhusuthanan Seethara Eclipse Classic 3.6.1 64-bit (on Windows 7).

Comment: @AndroidEve If you select a string in the editor the refactoring options will be enabled. But the refactoring will succeed only if it is a variable name, method name, class name etc. You cannot refactor/rename any random selection (for example an expression as a whole). The dialog box says that you have selected a random string instead of a Java identifier. Also renaming an identifier != renaming a project.

Comment: @Madhusuthanan Seethara Thanks for this clarification and +1 again. Where can I find more information about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved!

The problem turned out to be that I was trying to 'Refactor > Rename' while in the Resource perspective.

Once I switched to the **Java perspective**, this (inconsistent) behavior didn't repeat itself and I was even able to check the Update references checkbox.

Wow!

(thanks @Sankar Ganesh for posting the snapshots, because that allowed me to notice that there is an "Update references" checkbox and that the text on your caption bar is different than mine)

Answer (score 2):

I was wonder,why you struggling for Renaming a project,
 if you want to rename your project, then simply you can select your project, then click refactor menu, then Rename, that's it

step1:

[image]

Step2: Now see My project name is updated,initally it was friend finder, now friendfinderupdated

[image]

Also , you can use Extract Android String for Valid Java Identifiers and not for packages and files, because see window here

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I did. But I wanted to rename it again (to something else) and that's when I encountered a surprise... But all is well now, although I don't really understand how Eclipse "healed" itself. :)

Comment: Ganes BTW, in my Eclipse 3.6.1 I don't have the **Update references** checkbox.

Comment: @AndroidEve: Oh, Again i was wonder,without upUpdate references checkbox, you can modify your project name

Answer (score 1):

Pls select a String in your java code and do that Refactor -> Android -> Extract Android String, now you can see dialog, what i had shown below

[image]

and see next image

[image]

Comment: Wow! I just **selected** a string (without even reaching the 'Extract Android String' step) and the entire Refactor menu is available again. Why? Is this how Eclipse Refactor should behave? If so, where do I find more information?

Comment: @AndroidEVe: oh, Selecting a String , throws this dialog to you, am i right?

Comment: No, I didn't even reach this dialog yet. See my update above. I think I need to do a PhD on the Refactor function before attempting to use it. :)